# Como obter a data de criação de um índice no SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, tsql, índices

Pelo SQL Server Management Studio não encontrei nas propriedades de um índice a sua data de criação.

Como posso obter a data de criação de um índice específico consultando apenas pelo nome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pela documentação do [Microsoft SQL Server - sys.indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173760%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, não existe nenhum campo que armazene a data de criação de indexes.

[Uma pesquisa](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/28d20eb9-8b40-45cc-acf1-bee90d070f09/index-creation-date?forum=transactsql) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> no próprio site da Microsoft SQL Server revela que essa informação não é guardada em nenhum lugar, que só através de um `trace` criado por ti é que consegues manter-te a par dessa informação.

Para os casos em que o index é também PK ou UQ, o mais próximo que tens efetivamente é a data de criação desse objecto no [sysobjects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260447%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>, mais precisamente o campo `crdate`.

---

Em outros sites da SE a mesma pergunta já foi colocada no decorrer destes anos e até ao momento a resposta é que não é possivel:

- [Database Administrators - *SQL Server: index creation date*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/sql-server-index-creation-date) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>
- [StackOverflow - *Get index creation date from SQL server*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579932/get-index-creation-date-from-sql-server) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>

Answer (score -3):

Estou sem MSSQL aqui, mas tente isso.

```
 SELECT CREATE_DATE FROM SYS.INDEXES I
 INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS O ON I.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID
 WHERE I.NAME = 'NOME_DO_INDICE'
```

Comment: Essa é a data da criação do objeto na sysobjects, não do índice.